# How to exclude archived items from search in Trello?

Tags: trello, search

When I search in Trello, I usually want to exclude archived cards. But Trello seems to include them by default. I can manually add `is:open` to the search to exclude them. But how can I make this the default?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way currently to do this by default, but there's a relatively simple workaround.

If you have Trello Gold, you can save that search and open it anytime. Simply choose "Save this search" in the search box and your search will appear in the dropdown anytime you search.

You can also bookmark the search:

`https://trello.com/search?q=is%3Aopen`

I believe the last option works regardless of Trello gold.

EDIT: Clarified that this is a workaround.

Answer (score -1):

THis is what really annoys me about Trello. Why would we want to see archived tasks - at all, let alone in search. I would use Trello if not for this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/155072)